# how can I import images from facebook account to my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to take images from facebook account to my iphone, so what should I do to achieve such concept?

Comment: see my answer..you got your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking deeper through http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api may be it will give you the solution of your requirement.

In order to get the users profile pic...

http://graph.facebook.com/000000000/picture

Where 000000000 is an id of user logged.

Comment: how can I get id of particular friend by using programming?

Comment: You can't because id is generated when the user logged in......try to login to the docs you will get your id

Comment: I am asking according to my iphone perspective, how do I get sign in and get my id ?