# iOS :How to get Facebook Album Photo's Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Is Facebook iOS SDK provide any default *(Facebook)* album Photo's picker like `UIImagePickerController` does?

I heard of this so searched for it from long but couldn't find anything.

Please let me know if someone have any thoughts on this. If its not, then I'll surely need to make my own.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Import from Facebook

**without third party tool get a facebook photos from album Working For graph api 2.4 , 2.5, 2.6,2.7,2.8 & Facebook graph api 2.10**

1) Add App in Facebook developer account

2) then choose platform in app for better understand see following screen shot

[image]

3) Choose ios & follow All Step Display in wizard

4) then go to graph api explore https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

5)select your application in graph api explorer For more understand display screen shot

[image]

6) Click on Get token ..then click on get access token in a get token you can see so many permission for better understand see images

[image]

7) For Checking Your Permission on or off for getting album name & images display following  screen shot

[image]

if user_photos permission is not on then display error see following screen shot 
[image]

After completing step 7 either go for below steps or just download Coding files. I have put link Where you can download

**Coding files for objective c**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ysek035ek88xuw/FacebookAlbum%20Demo.zip?dl=0

8) if there is no error display then following code in your **viewDidLoad** method in view controller.this code for getting album name & album ids.

**objective C**

```
     FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_photos"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)

    {

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
          initWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"
          parameters: nil
          HTTPMethod:@"GET"]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {

               //  NSLog("%@",result);

                 NSArray *data = [result valueForKey:@"data"];


                 name = [data valueForKey:@"name"];

                 ids = [data valueForKey:@"id"];


                 [self.Fbtableview reloadData];


             }


         }];
```

9) now getting album cover photos following code type in **tableview cell for row**

**objective C**

```
 coverid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@?fields=picture",[ids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; **// pass album ids one by one**


/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:coverid
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error)
 {

    // NSLog("%@",result);

     NSDictionary *pictureData  = [result valueForKey:@"picture"];

     NSDictionary *redata = [pictureData valueForKey:@"data"];

     urlCover = [redata valueForKey:@"url"];



     NSURL *strUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlCover]];

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:strUrl];
     UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
     UIImageView *img1;

     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
     {
         img1= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 50, 50)];
     }
     else
     {
         img1= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 40, 40)];
     }



     [img1 setImage:img];
     [img1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:img1];


 }];
```

10)now code for getting album photos id.

```
 // code in **table didselect method**
```

**objective C**

```
   NSString *strAlbumid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos",[ids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:strAlbumid
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {

    // NSLog("%@",result);
    NSDictionary *data = [result valueForKey:@"data"];

    arrId = [data valueForKey:@"id"];



    PhotoViewControllerr *photoViewcontroller;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        photoViewcontroller = [[PhotoViewControllerr alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController_Ipad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        photoViewcontroller = [[PhotoViewControllerr alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
    }


    photoViewcontroller.picsArray = arrId;

    [photoViewcontroller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];




    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:  photoViewcontroller animated:YES];


}];
```

11) another view controller one now code for getting images in **collection view cellforRow**

**objective C**

```
NSString *strAlbumid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/?fields=images",[self.picsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:strAlbumid
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error)
{

    //NSLog("%@",result);
    picture_images = [result valueForKey:@"images"];

    NSMutableArray *picCount = [picture_images objectAtIndex:picture_images.count - 1];



     NSURL *strUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[picCount valueForKey:@"source"]]];


    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        /* Fetch the image from the server... */
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:strUrl];
         UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
         {

         img1= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
         }
         else
         {

         img1= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
         }



         img1.image = img;
         img1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:img1];

         });
         });



}];
```

12) After getting data you must be submit your app in facebook for submit you can filling information in

1)app details

2)status and review

=====

**If you have any query then I will help you**

enjoy.happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can i login with a static user ?

Comment: i want to put in a username and password manuel so that my view controller dont show the login popup, but always get albums from the facebook page i set.

Comment: Can you please share Swift files also.

Comment: @Maulik Do you have swift 3 code? I am almost done but getting an unusual error in my photos i am getting

Answer (score 2):

Facebook iOS SDK isn't providing such thing for now. Instead I found a third party class which does exactly same thing. https://github.com/OceanLabs/FacebookImagePicker-iOS/

Comment: it's provided still I tested