# How to download album pictures using facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want to display photos from one of my facebook albums on my webpage with the javascript api. how to do ? step by step procedure.... helpful for me thanx

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: answer for ios but may be helped.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score -1):

```
/{user_id}/albums
```

gives data for all albums a user has. It will give a JSON. Parse it to get your desired album's id.

```
/{album-id}/photos
```

gives data for all photos in an album. Parse it to get the id of all the photos.

```
/{photo-id}
```

gives data about the photo including the link to it on Facebook. Parse it to get your link. Do it for every photo you want. Better take a loop for all photos in an album.

Comment: ok @iron_monkey I did what you tell all going well,  but at the end photo_id didnt gave right json . it is not showin any link just only three fields id,name,createdtime any help using GraphAPi Version 2.4 FacbookSDK