# Error: No values for album, Fetching Album Photos from facebook in android

Tags: android

https://github.com/GrioSF/AndroidFBPhotoPicker
I am Using Above Code for reference but demo is also returning same response (no values for album)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: see my answer...this is for ios...but you helped lot of...follow 7 step then find your android code...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Comment: if you have any query i will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to fetch album from Facebook and it works for me.

```
LoginButton loginButton=new LoginButton(MainActivity.this);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_friends","user_photos");
loginButton.performClick();//call this method to your button click

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
           loginResult.getAccessToken(),
           new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(
                       JSONObject object,
                       GraphResponse response) {
                   try {
                     // parse your JSON here....


                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

               }
           });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,albums");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
```