# Get facebook album give error code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use simple app but cannot understand next:

Opened 2 urls:

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.675416519138045.1073741830.660049570674740&type=3

AND

https://www.facebook.com/joyasmariajose.valdivieso/media_set?set=a.383620231706322.80737.100001750452794&type=3

When I use Graph Exploder:

GET \675416519138045

return all information about album in this user

But When I try

GET \383620231706322

I can get only user_id and name. On the album have next error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Hb9lKBi2Wpz"
  }
}
```

Question: What can be wrong with second url ?

Comment: You likely simply don’t have permission to view that album via API.

Comment: see my answer ...may help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Comment: But this users are not friend to me and I use Graph Explorer API and all permissions to this token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unsupported get request` usually means that you can't access that resource without an Access Token, i.e. you don't have permissions to this object, as @CBroe said.

Comment: I use Graph Explorer API and all permissions to this token. 
All users are not friends to me.

Comment: You can't request resources of people which haven't given your app permission to do so. That's how Facebook Login / OAuth works.