# Facebook Graph API get photos returns with duplicated size.? Can I reduct the return?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How should I removed the duplicated size photos?
I just want one size for each photo.
But it returns images array and each array is one image with different sizes.

The service I'm calling is:

```
{user-id}/photos/uploaded?fields=images
```

returns:

```
"data": [
{
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 960,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/v/t1.0-9/10734238_10204858324278565_766379049543592577_n.jpg?oh=6ece9809697d2ca4019087d2173702d3&oe=56D2FB6C",
      "width": 720
    },
    {
      "height": 800,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/v/t1.0-0/p600x600/10734238_10204858324278565_766379049543592577_n.jpg?oh=8aabb9ba4538fdcf853b8c9107601f15&oe=56941F5E&__gda__=1455658621_d167345958233195768c68333d481f1a",
      "width": 600
    },
    {
      "height": 640,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/10734238_10204858324278565_766379049543592577_n.jpg?oh=2810aba0ea4eda0ee5ff73b5df75a70c&oe=56C3DF77&__gda__=1452026196_7d112ea2ad4fa41b108a883a27819241",
      "width": 480
    },
```

Comment: facebook send multiple images....use you want

Comment: That's too much for using it in mobile applications I want to filter what exactly size I want. Others would reduce my application user experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to remove the `.  Once you indent the code by 4 spaces, this is redundant.

Comment: see my answer....import from facebook....i  use lowest image & highest image....for my app requirement....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Comment: @Maulik Thanks, awesome!

Comment: @RohitGupta Thanks :)