# Facebook Graph API query for latest album from page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9

I want to know if there's a way to express in a facebook query, "From this facebook page, get me all the photos from the most recent album that contains 'Week' as the first word of the album name".  Can this be done?  I'm using the iOS SDK by the way.  Thanks!

Comment: No. You would need to request all albums, and check their name and creation date on your end.

Comment: yes.CBroe you are right.. get all album from facebook...see my answer...you may be helped...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234