# Fetch user albums using facebook latest SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I would like to retrieve entire user photos from Facebook using latest SDK for creating much like a gallery using facebook images.i had tried the below code from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums/) and couldn't make it.ain't getting any data from fb.can anyone show me any sample tutorial belongs to this or help to do this ?

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/albums",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: hi this is my ios answer...you may be helped...if you have any query then  i will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-how-to-get-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code..

```
 private ArrayList<FacebookAlbum> alFBAlbum = new ArrayList<>();
/*make API call*/
  new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  //your fb AccessToken
                    "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/albums",//user id of login user
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Facebook Albums: " + response.toString());
                            try {
                                if (response.getError() == null) {
                                    JSONObject joMain = response.getJSONObject(); //convert GraphResponse response to JSONObject
                                    if (joMain.has("data")) {
                                        JSONArray jaData = joMain.optJSONArray("data"); //find JSONArray from JSONObject
                                        alFBAlbum = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < jaData.length(); i++) {//find no. of album using jaData.length()
                                            JSONObject joAlbum = jaData.getJSONObject(i); //convert perticular album into JSONObject
                                           GetFacebookImages(joAlbum.optString("id")); //find Album ID and get All Images from album
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("Test", response.getError().toString());
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

GetFacebookImages method

```
    public void GetFacebookImages(final String albumId) {
//        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + "me" + "/"+albumId+"/photos?access_token=" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() + "&fields=images";
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "images");
        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + albumId + "/photos",
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
                        Log.v("TAG", "Facebook Photos response: " + response);
                        tvTitle.setText("Facebook Images");
                        try {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {


                                JSONObject joMain = response.getJSONObject();
                                if (joMain.has("data")) {
                                    JSONArray jaData = joMain.optJSONArray("data");
                                    lstFBImages = new ArrayList<>();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jaData.length(); i++)//Get no. of images {
                                        JSONObject joAlbum = jaData.getJSONObject(i);
                                        JSONArray jaImages=joAlbum.getJSONArray("images"); get images Array in JSONArray format
                                        if(jaImages.length()>0)
                                        {
                                            Images objImages=new Images();//Images is custom class with string url field
                                            objImages.setImage_url(jaImages.getJSONObject(0).getString("source"));
                                            lstFBImages.add(objImages);//lstFBImages is Images object array
                                        }
                                    }

                                   //set your adapter here
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.v("TAG", response.getError().toString());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
```

Response from first request for get Album

```
    {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[{"created_time":"2015-11-20T08:12:11+0000","name":"Untitled Album","id":"********"},
{"created_time":"2015-11-19T10:21:11+0000","name":"Mobile Uploads","id":"******"},
{"created_time":"2015-11-19T10:23:13+0000","name":"Timeline Photos","id":"*********"},
{"created_time":"2015-11-19T09:32:30+0000","name":"iOS Photos","id":"*******"},
 {"created_time":"2015-11-16T07:01:13+0000","name":"m","id":"***"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MTgzNzE3MTExOTcyMzMy","after":"MTgxOTg2NTI1NDc4NzI0"},"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/USERID\/albums?access_token=*************************&limit=25&after=*********"}}, error: null}
```

Response from request for get images from perticular Album

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[{"images":
[{"height":480,"source":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xfa1\/v\/t1.0-9\/***_***_***_n.jpg?oh=***&oe=5715F3A6","width":360},
{"height":426,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p320x320\/1169**9**9_***_**_n.jpg?oh=***&oe=***&__gda__=1457348501_***","width":320},
{"height":225,"source":"https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/p75x225\/&&&_***_***_n.jpg?oh=***&oe=56D5CA47&__gda__=***_3ac27adf32ef0b1537657dc5e88616f6","width":168}],
"id":"&&&&539"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"*******","after":"*********"}}}, error: null}
```

Comment: Ohkay..please post the sample response format also or link me into the tutorial where u get this.thank u

Comment: @Stella For Response format ,please check my edited ans.

Comment: Thank you very much i will check and accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98641/discussion-between-vimal-gajera-and-stella).

Comment: I am getting  `{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}`  do u know why it's happening ?

Comment: In this fb account,albums are there or not? if no error ,means work perfectly.

Comment: Albums is there in account.shall we need to do anything regards to permission  ?

Comment: I think ,you added this code in oncreate 
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
no other permission required

Comment: to get user albums we need to give review for user_photos permission..is that permission really required to get logged in user albums?

Comment: Does `alFBAlbum` get filled anywhere?