# How to fetch facebook photo album of login user using new facebook SDK 4.8.0 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I used following function to get images:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/{album-id}/photos" parameters:params  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

**Anybody can help me how will i get album_id??**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" parameters:@{@"fields": @"photos"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];            
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result::::%@",result);
    // Handle the result
}];
```

This code returning the empty JSON data. Can anyone help me to fetch my Facebook photo albums?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you asked the permissions for user photos while registering your app. Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-how-to-get-facebook-album-photos-picker

Comment: Yes.I have permission for user_photos permission

Comment: JSON will return empty data.Like {
    data =     (
    );
}

Comment: While using login have you asked for the permission to access photos [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_photos"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)

Comment: see my answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-how-to-get-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Comment: login into your fb a/c & check response in graph api

Comment: Yes Maulik i have checked it i got images for only same account from which i have made facebook key.. If i login with different facebook account i get empty JSON

Comment: @AshwiniSaste, were you able to solve your issue of getting images for only the same account from which you have made facebook key