# How to get photos from a facebook page without login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am making photo viewer app. I want to get photos from Facebook page without user needs to Login.

I know how to get photos from Facebook but I did not know how to get photos without login? I use facebook graph api 2.5 and I am also aware of graph explorer.

I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-how-to-get-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234) to get photos from Facebook but in this post login must be required.

So can we get Facebook page's photos without login?

Please help me on this.

Comment: If that's possible (And I am not saying it is, I don't know), You will only be able to fetch public photos.

Comment: ok i know that without login i get only public photos but i don't know how to get photos without login

Comment: The main question here is : What do you know?

Comment: i didn't  know how to get fb photos without login@Vizllx

Comment: Here is the ink https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed , then you can easily manage the things by yoursef to fetch photos from feed.

Comment: facebook pages are public in general, so...ALL photos of a page are public. and the public feed api is the wrong way to get photos from a specific page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the endpoint to get photos from a Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Reading

You can use an App Access Token if the Page is not restricted by age or location - no login required. If the Page is restricted, you need to use a User Token of a User who is allowed to see the Page and its contents - or a Page Token if you manage the Page.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/