# how to access all images from facebook in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift5

I am trying to access all the images form facebook that user uploaded
I try it with **user_photos**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_photos

I also try graph API explore from this 
[iOS :How to get Facebook Album Photo's Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-how-to-get-facebook-album-photos-picker)

**my code**

for **Login**

```
  func btnFbClicked()
        {
        fbLoginManager.logOut()
        fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .web
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_photos"], from: self) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
        print("error occured with login \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }

        else if (result?.isCancelled)!
        {
        print("login canceled")
        }

        else
        {
        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil
        {

        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(normal), email,gender"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, userResult, error) in

        if error != nil {

        print("error occured \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
        else if userResult != nil {
        print("Login with FB is success")
        print(userResult as! [String:Any])

        self.fbData = (userResult as? NSDictionary)!

        let mutableFBDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: self.fbData)
        print(mutableFBDict)


        if((mutableFBDict["email"] as? String) ?? "") == ""{


    //    self.showAlertNoHide(title: "", message: "If permission is granted then please set any email as a primary email in facebook general settings, then only facebook will return email to third party application. Sorry for the inconvenience.")

        return
        }


        var gender = Int64()
        if(mutableFBDict["gender"] as? String == "male")
        {
        gender = Int64(1)
        }
        else  if(mutableFBDict["gender"] as? String == "female")
        {
        gender = Int64(2)
        }
        else
        {
        gender = Int64(0)
        }



        self.fetchListOfUserPhotos()
}
```

**for fetching Photos**

```
func fetchListOfUserPhotos()
    {
        guard let id  = self.fbData["id"] as? String else
        {
            return
        }
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: id + "/photos" , parameters: ["fields":"user_photos"], httpMethod: "GET")


        //FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: id + "/photos" , parameters: nil, httpMethod: "GET")

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")

                let fbResult:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]

                self.userPhotos = fbResult["data"] as! NSArray?

                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()

            }
        })
    }
```

**Respons** I get

```
Optional({
    data =     (
    );
})
```

so my question is can access images that user uploaded on facebook or facebook change policies?

Answer (score 0):

```
"fields":"user_photos"
```

`user_photos` is a permission, not a field for API requests. About the existing fields for photos, check out the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

If you don´t get any photos, debug your Access Token and make sure it really is a User Token that includes the `user_photos` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: i already set the permission  fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_photos"], from: self) { (result, error) in
    
    if error != nil
    {
    print("error occured with login \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    }
    
    else if (result?.isCancelled)!
    {
    print("login canceled")
    }

Comment: i also try with     let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: nil ) but it's not work for me.

Comment: you still need to debug the access token to make sure you´ve authorized correctly. the response looks like user_photos is not authorized.

Comment: can you plz let me know how to  authorized for user_photos ?

Comment: i thought that´s what you tried already? do you even get asked for the requested permissions? and did you debug the access token, as i have pointed out?